# How to get suite name from specdone?

Tags: javascript, jasmine

I am working on a jasmine custom reporter and i was wondering if there is a way to get the name of the suite in specdone because even if a spec in a suite fails the suite array has failedExpectations of length 0. so is there any parent of any other method that can be used?